# How do I retrieve json objects nested in a json array from a retrofit response through my pojo class

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit

I'm working with a login api the sends a complex response when login is successful. I'm having problems implementing the retrieved array in the POJO class created for the response. The array contains two nested objects.

I tried using an arraylist to retrieve it but I'm getting an error

```
public class User{
   String id;
   String name;
   String email;
   String email_verified_at;
   @SerializedName("user_agents")
   private ArrayList<UserAgents> userAgents ;



    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail_verified_at() {
        return email_verified_at;
    }

    public void setEmail_verified_at(String email_verified_at) {
        this.email_verified_at = email_verified_at;
    }
```

UserAgents.java

```
  public class UserAgents{

  public UserAgents(){
      device = "";
      token_id = "";
    }

    @SerializedName("device")
    String device;

    @SerializedName("token_id")
    String token_id;

    public String getDevice() {
        return device;
    }

    public void setDevice(String device) {
        this.device = device;
    }

    public String getToken_id() {
        return token_id;
    }

    public void setToken_id(String token_id) {
        this.token_id = token_id;
    }
}
```

The expected JSON format is:

```
    "user_agents": "
                    [
                        {"device":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; 
                          rv:42.0) Gecko\/20100101 Firefox/42.0",      
"token_id":"ec4eccb011beb3c41f11e83f670ae635117770ac7bc9fb2ac3fbdac3645c16e63e64038d2ad0aa3c"
                        },
                        {"device":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0",
                            "token_id":"8e2bfef45fda2387ede9aa06d71247873db6390f3bf1e5c704cf51e76e3ecbd25cacdfb276464404"
                        }
                    ]"
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
>   at    line 1 column 145 path $.success.user.user_agents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the `user_agents` contains ""

So there is your `user_agents` is String

You need to remove `""` from `"user_agents": [ ]`

```
{
  "user_agents": [
    {
      "device": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0",
      "token_id": "ec4eccb011beb3c41f11e83f670ae635117770ac7bc9fb2ac3fbdac3645c16e63e64038d2ad0aa3c"
    },
    {
      "device": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0",
      "token_id": "8e2bfef45fda2387ede9aa06d71247873db6390f3bf1e5c704cf51e76e3ecbd25cacdfb276464404"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. The "user_agents" is supposed to be the name of the json array following normal JSON naming convention. removing "" should give an error. Please  help with more explanation. Thanks

Comment: Please check your JSON here https://jsoneditoronline.org/  here you get the error

Answer (score 0):

your response handling is not proper, as per error, web-service response is type of string but you set model class which is type of array,

or share web-service response for better solution.

removing "user_agents" keyword from response.

your web-service response must be this,

```
[ {"device":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0",
"token_id":"ec4eccb011beb3c41f11e83f670ae635117770ac7bc9fb2ac3fbdac3645c16e63e64038d2ad0aa3c" }, {"device":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0", "token_id":"8e2bfef45fda2387ede9aa06d71247873db6390f3bf1e5c704cf51e76e3ecbd25cacdfb276464404" } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

*THIS WILL WORK *

```
    JSONObject JO = new JSONObject(jsonresponse);
    JSONArray JA = (JSONArray) JO.getString("user_agents");
    for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject)JA.get(i);
                UserAgents UA = new UserAgents();
                UA.device = jo.getString("device");
                UA.token_id =jo.getString("token_id");
                userAgents.add(UA);
            }
```